# Getting a Nan but would like a 0 in vue

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to get my total to show 0 if there is nothing. I have a from that will add 2 numbers together and then display
a total. The problem I'm having is that it is displaying NaN instead of a 0.

Here is my code

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Price</label>
                    <input type="text" name="price" class="form-control" v-model="price">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <label>VAT</label>
                <input type="text" name="vat" class="form-control" v-model="vat">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div v-model="total">{{ productTotal }}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data(){
            return {
                price: '',
                vat: '',
                total: ''
            }
        },
        computed: {
            productTotal(){
                let total = parseInt(this.price) + parseInt(this.vat);

                return this.total = total;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Either initialize the numbers to 0 instead of an empty string `''` or cast the string variables to numbers:

```js
let total = parseInt(Number(this.price)) + parseInt(Number(this.vat));
```

Also, the computed shouldn't create side effects such as setting values to other variables like `this.total`, use a method for that.  In fact, there is no need for both if they are the same.